# C# LINQ get first list items of a dictionary<string, List<object>>

Tags: c#, linq

I have a dictionary of lists and I would like to get a list of the first elements of each list in the dictionary. Basically:

```
    Dictionary<string, List<object>> dico = new Dictionary<string, List<Object>>();

    // fill data...

   List<object> list = new List<Object>();
   foreach(var value in dico.Values)
   {
        list.Add(value.ElementAt(0));
   }
```

Can this be done with LINQ.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: "Can this be done with LINQ." Um, yes. And that's what you did. What are you looking for?

Comment: Can you show what you have attempted?

Comment: Why would you use `ElementAt` when you have a `List<object>`?  Just do `value[0]`, though you risk an exception in both cases if the list is empty.

Answer (score 4):

`Dictionary` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair>` so you can project from each value to what you want, then convert to a list:

```
var list = dico.Select(p => p.Value[0]).ToList();
```

If you are concerned with empty `List`s or missing (`null`) lists, you can protect the projection:

```
var list = dico.Select(p => p.Value?.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

PS I thought `ElementAtOrDefault` was a method of `List`, or at least special cased for `List`, but it is not. I wonder why .Net uses type conversion to check for `List` instead of also a special case for when static types are known:

```
public static T ElementAtOrDefault<T>(this List<T> src, int index) => src.Count > index ? src[index] : default(T);
```

A quick test indicates the extension method is 20 times faster on a `List`.

Comment: Couldn't you just use `FirstOrDefault()`?

Comment: @maccettura Yes. I thought `ElementAtOrDefault` was special-cased or a method on `List`, but it has special casing inside its body for `List` instead.

Comment: `I wonder why .Net uses type conversion to check for List instead of also a special case for when static types are known:` The way it has been built means you get the performance benefit even if your `List` has been cast to `IEnumerable` somewhere. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/guidelines-for-collections#collection-parameters -> `Instead, consider using IEnumerable<T> or IEnumerable and dynamically checking whether the object implements ICollection<T> or ICollection.`

Comment: Interestingly, the reference source checks for `IList` since it uses indexing. I wouldn't suggest removing that check from `ElementAtOrDefault(IEnumerable)`, just adding the additional statically typed version.

Comment: What benefit would that achieve? _The existing way has the same benefit with only one method required._

Comment: As I pointed out the existing method is **20 times slower**. WIth a static type version, the compiler picks a version that does not have to test the object type at runtime and decide which method to use.

Comment: Interestingly a version on `IList` is twice as slow as a version for `List`, but still much faster than the `Enumerable` version.